# generating 3 numbers whose sum is n

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to generate three natural numbers whose sum is `n`. The first number can be at max `x`, the second number can be at max `y` and the final number can be at max `z`. Currently I am doing this

```
def f(n):
    return [(i, j, k)
            for i in range(x+1)
            for j in range(y+1)
            for k in range(z+1)
            if i + j + k == n]
```

But `n` is very large, around `500` and `x, y, z` are less than 200.  Currently I have 3 variables `(i, j, k)` generated from 3 ranges. Can this be done using two loops inside list comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

Yup,

You can just compute the third number and check that it's in the right range (Martijn Pieters♦).

```
[(i, j, n - i - j) for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) if 0 <= n - i - j <= z]
```

Comment: might be better to explain how it works using something more than Yup

Comment: @SantoshLinkha: you don't need to loop through all possible values in the range `z`; you can just *calculate* `k`. Which is what this code is doing; it verifies that the calculated `k` is between `0` and `z`. This saves you an entire loop.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is constrain the second variable (`j`) depending on the value of the first (`i`), and the last one (`k`) depending on the 2 firsts:

```
l = []
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    for j in range(max(1, n - x - z), min(y + 1, n - x - 1)): # No need to go above n - x - 1or bellow n - x - z
        # For k, you do not even need a loop since it is constrained by i and j
        k = n - i - j 
        if 0 < k <= z:
            l.append((i, j, k))
```

I am not using list compression to details the code, but of course you can:

```
[(i, j, n - i - j) for i in range(1, x + 1) for j in range(max(1, n - x - z), min(y + 1, n - x - 1)) if 0 < n - i - j <= z]
```

When `x` equals `1` (first value in the global loop), the range for `y` goes from `n - x - z = 500 - 1 - 200 = 299` to `200`, i.e. you do not even enter the `y` loop, and that's normal since you need `x` to be at least `100` to be able to reach `500` (because `y` and `z` are at most `200`).

Every time you are facing this kind of problem, think about « How can you reduce the domain of the current variable depending on the already assigned variables? ».

By the way, doing the `k = n - i - j` assignment is equivalent of looping on a range of size `0` or `1` like so:

```
for k in range(max(1, n - i - j), min(z + 1, n - i - j + 1)):
    l.append((i, j, k))
```

Notice that in this case, you do not have to check for `0 < k <= z` anymore.

Comment: can this be done without if statement in the last? I want to reduce computation time as much as possible. Earlier I tried, `[(i, j, n-i-j) for i in range(min([x, n])+1) for j in range(min([y, n-i])+1)]` but it doesn't return correct value after certain number `n`. It can be assume that `x<=y<=z` here.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I don't think you can. With the constraints on `y`, you should be able to remove the `0 < z` part, but not the upper bound.